# What is the way increasing CPU quota of VM instance in Google Compute Engine while requests were rejecting all the time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, cpu, quota

I have a school project about parallel programming. For getting results and seeing the results are good enough, i need to increase CPU quota. I applied for increasing CPU quota in several amount -16, 24, 96- and several regions but it always rejected.

The ways that i use;

- All Quotas > Select the CPUs > Select the region > Edit Quotas > Write New Quota > Send.
- Edit VM instance > Select Higher CPU option > Error: Quota CPUs exceeded. Limit is 8 in region east-west-6.
- Write to Sales Support Team (They haven't answered, yet.)
- Write to Google Cloud Platform Support, they say; "However after careful evaluation, we have determined that we are unable to grant your quota increase due to insufficient service usage history within your preferred project. We suggest for you to make use of your current quotas and other resources readily available to serve your purposes for the meantime. To discuss further options on higher quota eligibility and to answer your questions, please reach out to your Sales team [1]" (Actually, i used this project for a while, at least for 5-6 months, not day by day, but frequently)

I have 8 CPU right now in my VM instance in Compute Engine - i was using Free Credit by the way but my credit card is added too. - I need higher quota amount. So, what is the way that i need to follow for increasing CPU quota amount after all?

Answer (score 1):

Try to [upgrade your free trial account to paid account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade). However, I checked on my account and indeed, I have quotas limitation per region (24 cpus for N1 type, 8 for other types (N2, N2D, C2))

Maybe that with a paid account, your quota increase request will be accepted! *In my case, it has been accepted in 2 minutes (N2 type, request of 16 CPUs, all regions)*

Comment: I have upgraded my account already but my free credit haven't done yet. So, i am not paying any cost for using VM instance. i made an another billing account too without free credit, but there is same issue in there too. My limit is still 8 and while i am using VM instance with new billing account, some payment is wrote.

Comment: I think the free credit isn't an issue. I also have free credit and I successfully increase the quota. However, 2 weeks ago, I tested to create (for a demo to a GDG) 2 GKE clusters (now by default with E2 cpu type). And I got an issue because I reached the CPU limit. It's maybe because I already hit the limit that I'm known as a user that is annoyed by quotas?

Comment: Yes, that might related with sentence in e-mail; " due to insufficient service usage history within your preferred project" but as i say, i used my account for a while, but i saw in another thread this might be solution too. Now, i was trying to use another  paid and upgraded google account but i got same answer again when i requested new limit. Thanks for your help, by the way. :)

Comment: I wasn't very helpful :( I hope you will find quickly a solution!

Comment: okay, i think i am still in free credit period -it hasn't done yet-. i think like this, because, all the restrictions of "free credit" is same with my situation. i selected my second billing account which is writing cost. but still my requests are rejecting. so, how can i get rid of this "free credit" period in a fastest way. do you have an idea?

Comment: @İstanbul were you able to find solution for this? I am facing same issue (Google always rejecting my requests) :(